# does heartbeat v3 support same resource agent types of pacemaker?

Tags: linux, heartbeat, pacemaker, heartbeat3

As we know, Pacemaker supports three types of Resource Agents,
   LSB Resource Agents,
   OCF Resource Agents,
   legacy Heartbeat Resource Agents

http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Resource_Agents

does heartbeat v3 support above 3 types resource agent? or it only support LSB and legacy heartbeat resource agents?
because we have only virtual ip and one service need to switch in ha cluster, so we decide not involve pacemaker, so we come to this question, for example we cannot monitor the application service by heartbeat, heartbeat only can handle to start it on active node.

thanks,
Emre

Answer (score 1):

heartbeat v3 is just a cluster messaging layer, it is no more a cluster resource manager. You need pacemaker if you want to use heartbeat v3. See also: http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Heartbeat